# fifo's write is not blocked

Tags: linux, fifo

I have a simple program

```
int main () {
  int fd;
  int i, rc;
  i = 0;

  rc = mkfifo ("fff", 0);
  fd = open ("fff", O_WRONLY);
  fprintf(stdout,"open fifo fff succeeded\n"); fflush (stdout);
  while (i<8)
  {
    rc = write (fd, "abcdefg", 8);
    fprintf(stdout,"write to 'fff' returned with rc=%d\n",rc); fflush (stdout);
    i++;
  }
  close (fd);
  return 0;
}
```

I run it on Unbuntu 16.04, Linux myserv 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP,
and I got the following:

```
open fifo fff succeeded 
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
write to 'fff' returned with rc=-1
```

It shows the open and write are both non-blocked without any process open for reading it.  According to the Linux manual page,

> . . . However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it. Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

Seems like I got a contradiction. Is there anything I missed? Expect an explanation about this.  Further, any suggestion to implement "blocked write" to a FIFO?

Comment: sorry,  asked a dumb question, i found why.  i should not set the accessibility (mode) to zero for `mkfifo`. mode zero means the fifo cannot be read, written or executed for any one, including myself.  all subsequent operations after creation are failed and hence unblocked.   after setting it `S_IRWXU`   the "open" does get blocked.

Answer (score 5):

Rule #1: Read the man page for everything you do.
Rule #2: When in doubt, do `ls -la`.
Rule #3: When debugging a program, print all variables.
Rule #3a: Don’t announce that something has succeeded without first checking that it really has succeeded.

The second argument to `mkfifo` is *mode*. 
You are creating a FIFO with mode (permissions) 0; i.e., `p---------`. 
So the `open` is failing with an EACCESS error, and returning `-1` for `fd`. 
And writing to a file descriptor of `-1` is failing with an EINVAL error.